# Bot framework directline conversation data

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I am using the Bot framework / DirectLine within a custom app. I replaced the default BotDataStore with a custom one (table storage using the bot builder extension).

But still, the conversation (I am talking about the collection of activities, not the state in UserData / PrivateConversationData) is stored somewhere else. Indeed, when I call directline API GetActivities with a watermark, I can get the history of the conversation even after deleting the content of my table storage.

Is there a way to get the conversation data ONLY stored in a custom storage (like a table storage) ?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

The **Direct Line** is a bot communication channel, not a message store.  In order to account for temporary connection issues, and provide stability, the Direct Line has a temporary cache of messages.  If a client loses connection, messages sent during the downtime can be retrieved by replaying from the last watermark.

Please see here for reference: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-DirectLineJS#resume-an-existing-conversation

Comment: I get that but if you are dealing with sensitive data, you may not want this behavior...